# Convert CKAN data API call from bytes into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to access data.gov.au datasets through their CKAN data API.
Unfortunately, the data API instructions are slightly outdated and do not seem to work. [Instructions found here](https://data.sa.gov.au/data/api/1/util/snippet/api_info.html?resource_id=86d35483-feff-42b5-ac05-ad3186ac39de).

So far, I've worked out that I am meant to query the dataset using `urllib.request`.

```
import urllib.request

req = urllib.request.Request('https://data.sa.gov.au/data/api/3/action/datastore_search?resource_id=86d35483-feff-42b5-ac05-ad3186ac39de')

with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
   data = response.read()
```

This produces an object of type bytes that looks like a dictionary data structure, where the dataset seems to be stored in `"records:"`.

[image]

I'm wondering how I can convert the data records into a Pandas DataFrame. I've tried converting the bytes object into a string and reading that as a json file, but the output is wrong.

```
# code that did not work
result = str(data, 'utf-8')
rdata = StringIO(result)
df = pd.read_json(rdata)
df
```

[image: Wrong output]

The output I would like to return looks like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that works:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

url = "https://data.sa.gov.au/data/api/3/action/datastore_search?resource_id=86d35483-feff-42b5-ac05-ad3186ac39de"
JSONContent = requests.get(url).json()
content = json.dumps(JSONContent, indent = 4, sort_keys=True)
print(content)
df = pd.read_json(content)
df.to_csv("output.csv")
df = pd.json_normalize(df['result']['records'])
```

You actually were near the solution. It is only the last step `df=pd.json_normalize(df['result']['records'])` you were missing.

[image]